# How do I insert multiple rows into a table for every row from another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: TB1 and TB2.

For every row from TB1, I want to insert N number of rows into TB2 using some values from TB1. How do I do that?

For example:

```
For each row in TB1
{
   For N in 1-10
   {
     insert into TB2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
     values (N, TB1.Col1, 'Good job', TB1.Col2)
   }
   commit;
 }
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join`.  Set up a table of numbers and then:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n union all select 2 . . . union all select 10
     )
insert into tb2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
     select n.n, TB1.Col1, 'Good job', TB1.Col2
     from tb1 cross join
          n;
```

Some things to note:

- The syntax for creating `n` varies by database.  For instance, MySQL doesn't support CTEs, so it needs to be a subquery instead.  Oracle requires `from dual`, and so on.
- For inserting rows from one table to another, you want `insert . . . select`, rather than `insert . . . values` for every row.

Finally, a generic SQL approach uses 10 passes on `tb1`:

```
insert into tb2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
     select 1, TB1.Col1, 'Good job', TB1.Col2
     from tb1 
     union all
     select 2, TB1.Col1, 'Good job', TB1.Col2
     from tb1 
     union all
     . . .
     select 10, TB1.Col1, 'Good job', TB1.Col2
     from tb1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another table (permanent or temporary) with the N numbers that you want to use, then cross join this list with `TB1`.  If that table is named `n_list` with a column named `N`, then:

```
insert into TB2
    (col2, col2, col3, col4)
select
    N,
    TB1.Col1,
    'Good job',
    TB1.Col2
from
    TB1
    cross join n_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for suggestions, I decided to poke around and ended up using a cursor and a for loop like this and it works for me...though not sure how sufficient it is.  And thanks for all the suggestions.

```
DECLARE
CURSOR myCursor IS 
    select col1, col2 from TB1;
tmp_rec myCursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
FOR tmp_rec in myCursor
  LOOP
    FOR N IN 1 .. 10
      LOOP
        insert into TB2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
        values (N, TB1.col1, 'Good job', TB1.col2);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```